# Keep getting "Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java."

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to do the command `sudo apt install git nodejs npm curl` but I keep getting an error message that I don't have java installed, even though I do. I've even installed the latest jdk on their website but still get this issue. For reference, I'm using a mac.

```
sh-3.2$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_341"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to use the [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) tool to install software. This is the standard software package management tool for several Linux distributions, but is not commonly used on macOS.

The `apt` command that ships with macOS is a stub for the deprecated [Annotation Processing Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/) that used to be part of the Java SE Development Kit (JDK). macOS ships with binaries corresponding to the ones provided with JDK distributions. These built-in commands attempt to dispatch to the corresponding tool in the currently installed JDK, or prints an error if this can't be done. In this case, the `apt` tool was removed from JDK 8 (aka 1.8) and later. It can only be found by installing JDK 7 or earlier.

However, solving this won't solve your overall problem, because this is a completely different tool that happens to share the same command name, but has nothing to do with installing software packages.

If you're following instructions for installing software, be sure you're referring to ones written for macOS and not Linux. While there are some similarities between these operating systems, there are also many differences, particularly in the standard command line tools.

If you don't have existing instructions to follow, consider trying [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh) to install these packages on macOS. It's popular, well-supported and capable of installing all of these packages.

On the other hand, if you really are intending to use the APT package manager on macOS (for example, via the [Fink project](https://www.finkproject.org)), you'll need to ensure that you've [correctly set up the `PATH` environment variable](https://www.finkproject.org/doc/users-guide/install.php#setup) so that the installed `apt` command is found before the `/usr/bin/apt` command that ships with macOS.