# I can’t run 'sudo apt install' on macOS even though Java is installed

Tags: java, python-3.x, sudo, python-3.11, java-runtime-compiler

I am trying to install python3.11-dev on my Mac, but I cannot run *any* `sudo apt-get` or `sudo apt` commands.

When I type `sudo apt-get install python3.11-dev` in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

However, I do have Java installed. When I type `java -version`, I get this:

```
java version "22" 2024-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22+36-2370)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22+36-2370, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have Python 3.11 and 3.10 installed and they work fine. I run simple Python programs locally.

This issue stems from trying to compile a wrapper C file that has an include statement that reads `#include <Python.h>`. When I compile it with the path to my Python 3.11 included, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
# include "Python.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I was told by peers who had the same issue that running `sudo apt install` on the python3.11 dev solves the issue, but I can't even run any `sudo apt` commands, so I am stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: `apt` is a command associated with Debian or Ubuntu. Who told you to try to use it on macOS?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so it would probably be a better fit for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (although I do agree with @Botje that the premise of this doesn't seem to make much sense on the face of it).

Comment: On a Mac, you should probably be looking at [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and they have helpful [Python docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python). Also unclear is what this has to do with Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep getting "Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73858394/keep-getting-unable-to-locate-a-java-runtime-that-supports-apt-please-visit-ht)